# Using Around to create a ListPlot with errorbars

Tags: plotting, around

I'm new at this program,and I have a simple question.
In the previus edition of Mathematica I used ErrorBars or ErrListPlot that allowed me plotting data with errorbars. Now I use Around and ListPlot, but I don'understand very well how does it works.
I have my data and error of the y-axis,but ,when I use Around, it gives me this results:

```
 listaaa = 
 Table[{assex[[i]], Around[asseyerr[[i]]]}, {i, 1, Length[assex]}]

 {{19484, Around[0.00064760085, 0.0008987315168065738]}, {58704.5, 
  Around[0.0006393142, 0.0008872433650646705]}, {98065, Around[
  0.0006429803, 0.0008923259071864831]}, {137726, Around[
  0.0006297199, 0.0008739416965610579]}, {177711, Around[
  0.0006325325, 0.0008778412490379453]}, {217728, Around[
  0.0006286999, 0.0008725274829986847]}, {257777, Around[
  0.0006315479000000001, 0.0008764759672648304]}, {297768, Around[
  0.0006304925, 0.0008750128219131993]}, {337786, Around[
  0.00063074495, 0.0008753629104805646]}, {377962, Around[
  0.00062550355, 0.0008680958326689542]}}'
```

The problem is that **asseyerr** is a Table with this elements:

```
asseyerr

{{0.0012831, 0.0000121017}, {0.00126669, 0.0000119384}, {0.00127395, 
  0.0000120106}, {0.00124769, 0.0000117498}, {0.00125326, 
  0.000011805}, {0.00124567, 0.0000117298}, {0.00125131, 
  0.0000117858}, {0.00124922, 0.000011765}, {0.00124972, 
  0.0000117699}, {0.00123934, 0.0000116671}}'
```

I just want to evaluate asseyerr like the y cordinate of my graph linked with it's relative error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Around[asseyerr[[i]]]` applies `Around` to the list of values, which gives the mean of the list. Compare:

```
Around[{3,1}]
```

with

```
Around[3,1]
```

I think you mean `Around@@asseyerr[[I]]`:

```
assex = {19484, 58704.5`, 98065, 137726, 177711, 217728, 257777, 297768, 337786, 377962};

asseyerr = {{0.0012831, 0.0000121017}, {0.00126669, 
0.0000119384}, {0.00127395, 0.0000120106}, {0.00124769, 
0.0000117498}, {0.00125326, 0.000011805}, {0.00124567, 
0.0000117298}, {0.00125131, 0.0000117858}, {0.00124922, 
0.000011765}, {0.00124972, 0.0000117699}, {0.00123934, 
0.0000116671}};

listaaa = Table[{assex[[i]], Around @@ asseyerr[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[assex]}];

ListPlot[listaaa]
```

[image: ListPlot with error bars]

An alternative, shorter way to define `listaaa` is

```
listaaa = Transpose[{assex, Around @@@ asseyerr}]
```

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful. I applied Around to an entire list of values ​​and not to the single one. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
asseyerr = {{0.0012831, 0.0000121017}, {0.00126669, 
   0.0000119384}, {0.00127395, 0.0000120106}, {0.00124769, 
   0.0000117498}, {0.00125326, 0.000011805}, {0.00124567, 
   0.0000117298}, {0.00125131, 0.0000117858}, {0.00124922, 
   0.000011765}, {0.00124972, 0.0000117699}, {0.00123934, 
   0.0000116671}};

asseyerr // Map[Around[Sequence @@ #] &] // ListPlot
```

[image]